# TestNG + Spring test: EntityManager return null with testng

Tags: java, spring, testng, spring-test

I am new to testng framework .while migrating to testng from junit ,entityManager return null value .its looks strange for me can any one spot my mistake . here i placed my code snippets.thank you .

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "school")
public class School {
    private Integer id;
    private String schoolName;
    private String address;

    getters and setters here
}
```

Test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:/applicationContext.xml" })
@Transactional
public class SchoolTest {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

String address,schoolName; 


@BeforeClass
public void init() {
    address = "chinna kadai st";
    schoolName = "SVM School";
}
@Test
public void save_school() {
    School school = new School();
    school.setAddress(address);
    school.setSchoolName(schoolName);
    entityManager.persist(school);
}
}
```

the above code is working well while using `Junit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class), you need to extend your test class from [AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/testng/AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests.html)

Read here for more info in [Spring Reference docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#testcontext-support-classes-testng).